# Shell : Сopy one directory to multiple directories

Tags: shell, cp

There is a directory `YYY` and a structure on the site:

```
site1.ru/wp-content/plugins/
site2.ru/wp-content/plugins/
...
site10.ru/wp-content/plugins/
```

Task: `YYY` directory to copy all directories `plugins` which are available on the server.

Comment: Apart from what have you tried, do you want to copy directory `YYY` to all plugin directories, or is it the other way round?

Comment: Plus this question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I need to copy a directory YYY (with plugin for Wordpress) in all "plugins" directories on my server.

Answer (score 2):

```
cp
```

only can copy only to one destination , so you have to use a loop or do something like

```
echo dir1 dir2 dir3 | xargs -n 1 cp file1
```

Which will copy `file1` to `dir1`, `dir2`, and `dir3`.  `xargs` will call `cp` 3 times to do this, see the man page for `xargs` for details.

Found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195655/how-to-copy-a-file-to-multiple-directories-using-the-gnu-cp-command

Comment: Breaks on whitespace

Comment: whitespace in dir name or file name ? u should be able to use "dir1" "dir2" and so on to stop that problem

Comment: Quotes won't help for the `dir`s. They are interpreted by the shell and passed to `exho`, which prints them separated by a space.  `xargs` then splits on whitespace, so how is it supposed to know whether the space was meant to be split on or a part of the name?

Answer (score 1):

`cp` only takes one destination at a time, so call it in a loop.

```
for d in */wp-content/plugins/; do
  cp -Rp YYY "$d"
done
```

Note that this snippet will keep going if any of the `cp` commands fail. To abort immediately on failure, run `set -e` first. To keep going (makes sense on permission denied, not on disk full) but still report errors, save the return status in a variable:

```
ret=0
for d in */wp-content/plugins/; do
  cp -Rp YYY "$d" || ret=1
done
return $ret      # from a function; `exit $ret` in a script
```